# is current flow in open circuit with wire length=λ?

Tags: electric-current, wavelength

if ac source connected to resistor in open circuit as shown below:
[image]

each wire length =λ/2(suppose wire resistance is zero)

is current flow?

Comment: *"is current flow?"* - (1) current doesn't flow, *charge* flows.  (2) Are you asking for the value of the AC (steady state) current through the AC source? Or (3) are you asking if there is charge flow at (some or all) points along the conductors?

Comment: current is average charge flow in a circuit
i just asked if current will equal 2.2 A as in close circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the impedance seen by your 100 ohm resistor is infinite. However, if you had quarter wavelength lines, this impedance would be zero and current would flow from your generator. This is because a transmission line transforms an open circuit to a short circuit at the frequency where its length becomes one fourth the wavelength in that frequency. 
If you don't know why that is, check this link on Wikipedia, under "Input impedance of transmission line": 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line#Input_impedance_of_lossless_transmission_line

EDIT: On the other answer about it being an antenna:
This is not a dipole antenna, a dipole antenna is half a wavelength , but in TOTAL. if you open the two wires of your circuit the total length would be a full wavelength. A dipole has a total length of Lambda/2 and is in fact what I wrote as another example above. This image should clear things up: 
[image]

Second EDIT:
The Photon pointed out that what I said was not entirely correct. As he says in the comments, no current flows into the antenna but there still exists a nonzero standing wave pattern for the voltage and current distributions on the line. 
In fact, you can solve the telegraphers equations for the line and derive this mathematically:
[image]

Comment: Current won't flow into the antenna (because of the node at $\lambda/2$). But current will flow **in** the antenna.

Comment: Yes there is a zero current point at the voltage source (node at lamba/2 as you said). But I don't understand what you mean by current flowing in the antenna and not into it.

Comment: of whether it's 1/4 or 1/2 or 1 wavelength or whether it's a transmission line or an antenna, there will be a standing wave on the structure. At some point in that standing wave there will be non-zero current. So somewhere *in* the antenna/line there will be current flowing.

Comment: When the generator sees an open circuit because of the current node (or equivalently a reflection coefficient of +1), all of its available power gets reflected back and nothing ever gets into the transmission line. Which means that the amplitude of that standing wave you're talking about is zero. i.e. there is no current on the whole transmission line. In fact, this is a major problem in properly feeding a full-wave antenna, for which one solution is using an off-center feed. See the following reference for details:

Antenna Theory and Design by Stutzman and Thiele, 3rd edition, page 180

Comment: that's simply not true.

Comment: Ok that's not very convincing, could you at least tell me where the faulty argument is in what I have said? doesn't all the available power of the generator get reflected when it sees an infinite impedance? Is that what you disagree with?

Comment: I agree that there is no net power transfer into the stub line.  However, the reason that's true and the reason the stub looks like an open at the feed point is precisely *because* of the (non-zero) reflected wave present in the stub. Another way to look at it: even though the current is 0 at the feed point, the voltage is non-zero, and that voltage is going to excite a forward travelling wave in the stub (which will be reflected at the far end to form a standing wave). Because there is a standing wave in the stub, there will be non-zero current everywhere along the stub except for the nodes.

Comment: I solved the Telegrapher's equations for this problem and you are right. I'm so sorry. I will edit my answer immediately. But I know for a fact that full-wave antennas have a problem because of the current node and need to be fed off-center, but I don't know if that's relevant to this anymore because what you said is entirely correct.

Comment: I wish that $100\Omega$ resistor were not drawn where it is.  I want to say that it, as drawn, isn't at the center current node and thus cannot be ignored.

Comment: Yes that is a bit misleading, I assume it means the resistor is connected to the source with zero electrical length (like its internal resistance for example).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is an antenna. The ammount of current will deppend on many factors, but shurely there will be some current. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna) for example.

Comment: yes this circuit inspired by dipole antenna but i make wire  λ/2 instead λ/4